# Expand phone numbers range into multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range of phone numbers in one cell that I want to have each phone number put in their own cell.  Example,

| Original range |
| --- |
| +1-3124440000 - +1-3124440010 |

I want to be each put into their own cell

| Expanded range |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| +1-3124440000 | +1-3124440001 | +1-3124440002 | ... |

Does anyone know how to go about this.  I have literally tried everything I know and there are 1000s of these so doing it manually is not really an option due to time constraint.

I have tried all functions and combinations of functions that I can think, but at this point my brain is mush.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `="+1-"&SEQUENCE(,RIGHT(A1,10)-MID(A1,4,10)+1,MID(A1,4,10))` looking at this sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You may try-

```
=LET(x,--TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+1-",""),"-")),y,SEQUENCE(MAX(x)-MIN(x)+1,,MIN(x)),TOROW("+1-"&y))
```

[image]